# Sending a Jinja2 templated email doesn't use new lines

Tags: python, jinja2, zabbix

My script accepts a variable from a Zabbix trigger (alert media). I'm trying to send that variable as an email but I don't see new lines in the email.

The original output has `^M` at the end of each line, so I replace them with `/n` and then send that to be rendered in my Jinja2 template:

```py
alert_message = sys.argv[1] # This is the variable I get from Zabbix
alert_message = alert_message.replace('\r', '\n')
f = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w") # I wrote the file to an output to see how it looks in raw text
f.write(alert_message)
f.close()
hostname = findGW(alert_message) # a function that uses regex to find the name of the hostname in the message
username = getOwner(hostname) # a function that gets the owner of the hostname to send him an email later
if username is not None:
    sendEmail(username, gw, alert_message) # Sending the email
else:
    print("Couldn't find gateway\nSkipping email sending")
```

This is my `sendEmail()` function:

```py
def sendEmail(username, hostname, alert_msg):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    title = f'Instance alert for {hostname}'
    cc = ['email@email.com']
    # owner_email = [f'{username}@email.com']
    owner_email = [f'user@email.com']
    sender = 'alert@email.com'
    rendered_template = MIMEText(email_template.render({'owner':username, 'hostname':hostname, 'alert_msg':alert_msg}), 'html')
    msg['Subject'] = title
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(cc)
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(owner_email)
    receivers = owner_email + cc
    msg.attach(rendered_template)
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver', 25)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
        print ("Successfully sent email")
        smtpObj.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print (e, "Error: unable to send email")
```

This is my HTML template which I render:

```html
<p>Owner: {{owner}}, VM: <strong>({{hostname}})</strong>.
<br>
<b>Issue Message:</b>
{{alert_msg}}
<br>
```

For some reason, this is the email:

[image]

Just to compare, I also write the file as an output, and it looks like this, which would suggest everything is working properly:

[image]

Given the above comparison I'm not sure where to look for the issue. Is it Jinja2 or my script?

Comment: I suspect an issue with the line endings that is mentioned in the docs for the `.as_string()`: _(instead of the RFC mandated \r\n, it uses the Python standard \n line endings)_ .  Try to set a policy (e.g. SMTP). Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage

Comment: @VPfB Wouldn't that already be applied? in my `sendEmail()` function: `smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())`. Or do you mean I should try sending the email without it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is easy to try with a policy: `msg.as_string(policy=email.policy.SMTP)` (add `import email.policy` if not imported already)

Comment: see also "By default, the Auto Remove Line Breaks feature in Outlook is enabled. This causes the line breaks to be removed. Any two or more successive line breaks are not removed." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text

Comment: Unfortunately @VPfB, the policy didn't do the trick. It might be something on the Outlook client side I guess.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for trying it out and reporting the result. But isn't the example of correct message rendering from the Outlook as well?

Comment: I changed the client settings to reflect the workaround that @IronBishop mentioned: `Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages`. I unchecked it, as it was checked by default, but the result was the same. In the meantime I was able to split the string into the relevant pieces and put them inside a dictionary, which allowed me to build my email template even though I'm not convinced it is "best practice". Sorry if I misunderstood your last question @VPfB

Comment: @Daniel You have shown how the message should look like. My question was if that screenshot was taken from the Outlook.

Comment: The screenshot of the one line message is a screenshot from my Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post an update. Not sure if this will help anyone since this is a pretty janky solution, but overall:

I get the message from Zabbix, parse it in my script, and send it in a templated email using Jinja.

The fuction:

```py
def parseMessage(message):
    d = {}
    for line in message.splitlines():
        if line.startswith("Problem name:"):
            problemMessage = line.split(":")[1].strip()
            d['Problem name'] = problemMessage
        
        if line.startswith("Problem started") or line.startswith("Problem has been resolved"):
            d['Start Time'] = line

        if line.startswith("Severity"):
            d['Severity'] = line.split(":")[1].strip()

        if line.startswith("Host:"):
            d['hostname'] = line.split(":")[1].strip()
    return d
```

Then the template looks something like this:

```html
<p>bla bla bla
<br>
{% if "Problem has been resolved" in issue_time %}
<p>
    This is an update to the previous email you received.
    bla bla bla
</p>
{% endif %}
<ul>
    <li>
        Issue Message: {{issue_message}}
    </li>
    <li>
        Issue Time: {{issue_time}}
    </li>
    <li>
        Issue Severity: {{issue_sev}}
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
```